# getting unsatisfiable error while installing mxnet on windows. I am using ANACONDA 5.1.0 VERSION AND PYTHON 3.5.3 VERSION

Tags: windows, error-handling, installation, anaconda, mxnet

I wanted to install MXNET using commands `conda install -c anaconda mxnet` and `conda install mxnet`, but I am getting unsatisfiable error as show in images.

**'conda install -c anaconda mxnet'**:
[image: FOR 'conda install -c anaconda mxnet']
**'conda install mxnet':**
[image: FOR 'conda install mxnet']

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the [install instruction on the website](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/install/index.html):
Select your preferred configuration, for example on windows, install mxnet using

`pip install mxnet`

Comment: THAT DID NOT HELP. INSTEAD I UNINSTALLED BLAZE. NOW IT IS WORKING.

Comment: THAT IS GREAT @m96!